# How can i pass the content of file as an arguments to some function?

Tags: c, eclipse, argv, argc

given file `a.txt` how can I pass the content of this file as arguments to the main function ?

for example:
**a.txt:**

```
a b c d e
```

and the main function is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

And I want to pass the content of this `a.txt` file as arguments to `main` function. Namely, the arguments will be: `a` `b` `c` `d` `e`.

How can I do it via Eclipse compiler ?

Comment: Why do you want to do it?

Comment: @Phalgun Because that I want to parser some file that I have in this way and to understand what is the chars that appears there

Comment: Why not read it from file within your program? But to your question - there is a `xargs` utility in Linux. Maybe there is something for windows too.

Comment: @meaning-matters how strange, in the link you provide the accepted answer with 294 upvotes does not work (it sends the whole file as a single argument)

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, you can configure parameters for running your code in the IDE...
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_run_configuration.htm

But programatically you will need a script that reads the contents of the file and constructs the command-line that invokes *main()* with those file contents as command-line parameters.

Or for an elegant one-liner, see this answer by David Ranieri...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736630/20006834